# how to change alert controller background color using ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4

How to change ion controller background color using ionic 4.
I was tried below code:

```
async presentAlert() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Add a new element',
      message: '<p> A great title is unique and descriptive! It should highlight the main attractions of your space.</p><p>Example</p><ul style="text-decoration:none"><li> Charming Victoria in the Mission.</li> <li>Cosy 2BD with Parking Included</li><li>Amazing View from a Mordern Loft</li></ul>',
      cssClass: 'alertCustomCss',
    });

    await alert.present();
```

CSS:

```
.alertCustomCss .alert-wrapper {
    background: #801ce4 !important;
  }
```

Comment: Did u put css in global.css ?

Comment: i was put this css in my page scss file

Comment: Can you try to put in global.css

Comment: @pc_coder How can we customize alert message text. I mean i need to apply some css in alert message like text-decoration:none and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you can see in **[the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert#css-custom-properties)**, instead of setting the `background`, you need to set the `--background` CSS custom property.

Please try by adding the following to the `global.scss` file:

```
ion-alert.your-custom-class {
  --background: #801ce4;
}
```

As far as I know, you can't add this style rule in the page scss file because the `ion-alert` element is a global element, and is not part of the page.

In general, if you want to change the styles of any Ionic component, always check the **[CSS custom properties section](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert#css-custom-properties)** of that component first to see if there're any CSS variables available for that change. If not, and if the element you want to change is not part of the shadow DOM of the component, you can just use CSS style rules like you did in Ionic 3 apps.